# How wp_enqueue_script works?

Tags: jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I am trying to get scripts via `wp_enqueue_script();`. I have tried this in header but WordPress is not importing any script.

I am using like this `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Is any other step needed for importing script via WordPress?

Comment: You state you are using the method in the header, to enqueue scripts if must be before the wp_head() call. Unless of course, you want the script to load the script in the footer.

Check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

Comment: Do i have to register script before enqueue? I thought some scripts are already registered by default in wordpress in wp-include/js folder

Comment: Yes there are a load of already registered scripts : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_scripts_included_with_WordPress but if you want to use a custom script, then you will have to register it.

Comment: It seems scripts are not registered in my case because wp_enqueue_script() is not working unless i register scripts again :(

Comment: I am registering scripts by this code. I know this code is not perfect. Can you suggest more nifty code?  `wp_register_script( 'jquery',  '/'. WPINC .'/js/jquery/jquery.js');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In simple case you need to enqueue script before header scripts are printed, which happens in `wp_head` hook.

Basic approach would be this in `functions.php` of your theme:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts');

function my_enqueue_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Comment: same result! Still scripts are not importing. But when i de-register then register the scripts again (with the path to the script in wp-include folder). Those are loading. What is the correct code for pointing the scripts in the wp-include directory?

Comment: @Sisir if bundled jQuery doesn't work for you it's likely that theme or some plugin breaks it, sadly not uncommon.

Comment: @Rarst : its not only jquery but all scripts :(

Comment: @Sisir what does this get you - `var_dump( wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'registered' ) );` ?

Comment: @Rarst: returning: `bool(true)`

Comment: @Sisir then I am out of ideas what goes wrong in your case :(

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort. I am de registering scripts which i need to include. So, its a way around for now.  
I am registering scripts by this code. I know this code is not perfect. Can you suggest more good code? `wp_register_script( 'jquery', '/'. WPINC .'/js/jquery/jquery.js');`

Comment: jQuery is already registered by WordPress so you won't need to do that again. In your theme you will need to make sure wp_head() and wp_footer() are being called. wp_head will be just before the </head> tag (or should be) and the wp_footer() should be in the footer.php file.

Comment: @Wild Phoenix yes, i know these basic stuff and double checked it after reading your comment. But i guess its not the reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you have copy/pasted your code, then you have a typo.

```
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Answer (score 1):

Read what the codex says... You should call this inside an action hook... Otherwise it may lead to troubles! Codex suggests you use it with 'init' action hook.

Comment: Yes! `init` action hook is the recommended place.

Comment: _Codex suggests you use it with 'init' action hook._ Actually it no longer does and that wasn't wildly correct either (too early for meaningful conditional queueing). `wp_enqueue_scripts` is most appropriate for front end.

Comment: yes. used the init action hook. But still scripts are not importing. However when i de-register then register the scripts again. Those are loading. By the way, what is the correct code for pointing the scripts in the wp-include directory?

Comment: You should not deregister and reregister them again. They are already registered. If they're not working, then you need to find the reason they're not working instead of trying a strange hack to work around it.

Comment: @Otto I know. Its just a work around until i find a solution. I know it may sound wired to you but i am working with wordpress about 6 months now and wp_enqueue_script never worked for me! Not even a single time. :(

Comment: Are you missing the wp_head call in your theme or something? Deregistering a script and reregistering it won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

^Listen to Otto Sisir!

This is what I usually do for enqueueing custom js on the admin side, ONLY for my plugin's settings page...

```
`add_action('admin_print_scripts-settings_page_<your-settings-page-slug>', 'add_my_scripts');
function add_my_scripts()
{
   //We can include as many Javascript files as we want here.
   wp_enqueue_script('pluginscript', plugins_url('/js/script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
}
```

`

By the way, all you can do is use 'wp_head' hook and call wp_enqueue_script('jquery') in the function, to use jquery on the frontend (theme) (same way you can include any Javascript library that is inside WP's js folder). I don't understand why and what you're doing by this...  `wp_register_script( 'jquery', '/'. WPINC .'/js/jquery/jquery.js');` !

Comment: because `wp_enqueue_script()` is not including jquery. That's the whole reason of this post. I want to point the script to the right one that in wp-includes directory.